# Resharper named arguments for methods, but position for expression trees

Tags: c#, resharper

We want to use named arguments for methods, so I changed my settings to this:

[image]

When I applied this style, it did put named parameters for all my methods. But it also updated any **linq** expressions I had, which causes this error:

> An expression tree may not contain a named argument specification

How can I get resharper to ignore linq expressions?

Here is some code before I applied the style:

```
public class MessageService : Service<Message>, IMessageService
{
    public MessageService(DbContext context) : base(context) { }

    public IQueryable<Message> List(string status) => List().Where(m => m.Status.Equals(status)).OrderBy(m => m.NiceEndpoint.StartsWith("PSC") ? 0 : 1).ThenBy(m => m.DateCreated);
    public IQueryable<Message> ListByType(string type, string status) => List().Where(m => m.Type.Equals(type, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && m.Status.Equals(status)).OrderBy(m => m.NiceEndpoint.StartsWith("PSC") ? 0 : 1).ThenBy(m => m.DateCreated);
    public IQueryable<Message> ListByEndpoint(string endpoint, string status) => List().Where(m => m.Type.Equals(endpoint, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && m.Status.Equals(status, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).OrderBy(m => m.NiceEndpoint.StartsWith("PSC") ? 0 : 1).ThenBy(m => m.DateCreated);
    public async Task<Message> GetAsync(string id) => await List().SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id.Equals(id));
}
```

And when I apply the code style above, I get this:

```
public class MessageService : Service<Message>, IMessageService
{
    public MessageService(DbContext context) : base(context: context) { }

    public IQueryable<Message> List(string status) => List().Where(m => m.Status.Equals(value: status)).OrderBy(m => m.NiceEndpoint.StartsWith("PSC") ? 0 : 1).ThenBy(m => m.DateCreated);
    public IQueryable<Message> ListByType(string type, string status) => List().Where(m => m.Type.Equals(value: type, comparisonType: StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && m.Status.Equals(value: status)).OrderBy(m => m.NiceEndpoint.StartsWith("PSC") ? 0 : 1).ThenBy(m => m.DateCreated);
    public IQueryable<Message> ListByEndpoint(string endpoint, string status) => List().Where(m => m.Type.Equals(value: endpoint, comparisonType: StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && m.Status.Equals(value: status, comparisonType: StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).OrderBy(m => m.NiceEndpoint.StartsWith("PSC") ? 0 : 1).ThenBy(m => m.DateCreated);
    public async Task<Message> GetAsync(string id) => await List().SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id.Equals(value: id));
}
```

As you can see, it has added named arguments to the linq expressions, which do not compile....

Comment: This bug should be fixed in ReSharper 2019.1. Which version do you use?

Comment: I shall give it a go and let you know

Comment: I can confirm that the latest version does work

Comment: Thanks, I'll create an answer in case somebody else has the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug should be fixed in ReSharper 2019.1, please update